# How to use AppEvents.activateApp() in 12.0.0 version

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-events

I have updated the **FBSDKAppEvents** to **12.0.0 version**, and the function AppEvents.activateApp() in AppDelegate is now deprecated. I have searched in the Facebook documentation, and unfortunately I didn't found any information about that, and I don't understand what's method I want to use to replace the deprecated:

[image: Deprecated function]

The message is:
"'activateApp()' is deprecated: The class method `activateApp` is deprecated. It is replaced by an instance method of the same name."

Did anyone know what code I have to put to replace the deprecated one?

Comment: Also interested in seeing the answer to this

Comment: I'm interested to know as well, I like to keep my code base clean of warnings :)

Comment: Hi! Did you find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have updated the FBSDKAppEvents to 12.0.0 version and now we can use this code below:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    AppEvents.shared.activateApp()
}
```

And some Settings on FDSDKAppEvents changed a little, and now we need to update to Settings.shared, for example:

```
Settings.shared.enableLoggingBehavior(.appEvents)
Settings.shared.enableLoggingBehavior(.developerErrors)
Settings.shared.enableLoggingBehavior(.cacheErrors)
Settings.shared.enableLoggingBehavior(.uiControlErrors)
Settings.shared.isAdvertiserTrackingEnabled = isEnabled
Settings.shared.isAutoLogAppEventsEnabled = isEnabled
Settings.shared.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = isEnabled
```

Answer (score 10):

Just in case for objective-c case:

```
[FBSDKAppEvents.shared activateApp];
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to update your code.
ı fix with this code

```
 AppEvents.shared.activateApp()
```

[image: Static change to Shared]

Comment: instead of using images that contains code use code blocks to make it easier for those who want to copy your code.

Answer (score 2):

According to [github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/1782) issue both solutions should work until FB team replace `singleton` with `shared`

We can use static method or singleton's instance method.